# Time Series Predictions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, time-series

I am new to PostgreSQL and database systems, and I am currently trying to create a database to store observed values as well as all predictions made in the past for some time series.

I have already built a table (actually a view) for observed values, with rows looking basically like:
(time, object, value)

Now I want to store predictions, which means for each time, what has been predicted by some software for the following next N time steps, N being variable since the software has different prediction types.

I have thought about multiple solutions, which are the following:

1. Store each prediction as a row, using max(N)=240 columns i.e (time, object, value 1, value 2, ..., value 240).
2. Store each prediction as a row, with the prediction values as a binary JSON,  i.e (time, object, JSONB prediction).
3. Store each prediction **value** as a row, with a column specifying the delay of the prediction in hours, i.e
   (time, object, delay, value).

I don't know how each of these choices would affect performance when I will retrieve and compute summary values on the predictions. A typical thing I would like to do is to retrieve the performance of the prediction for some delay, i.e. how big is the prediction error when we predict x days ahead, and I need this query to be executed pretty fast, to display it in a dashboard.

Which choice do you think is the best? Or do you have any other idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further information about the access patterns for the collected data i would strongly recommend to use `jsonb`.

Using one column per timestep will result in bloat of the system catalog and statistics.

If you need to filter on the values of the predictions, you don't want to maintain 240 indexes also.

If you don't need to use these values within a `WHERE` condition you may use `json` instead of `jsonb`.